# android : gradle build system using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am tired using Android Studio. I dont want to use Android Studio now. Using chrome with Android Studio results in 80% RAM utilization...!!!

My pc configuration is: core-i5 processor, 3GB DDR3 RAM, 512MB nVidia Cuda graphics card, but still...

Everything runs smooth as silk, but Android Studio... :(

I decided to switch over eclipse again (even though Android Studio comes with bunch of features). For now, I just wanted to use the feature of Studio for building android app, that is Gradle Build Automation System.

So, that I can easily integrate libraries and dependencies (like adding a single line of `compile'...'` installs the library into our project).

Is this possible, using eclipse ? I will compromise with rest of the features... :)  atleast for now..

A step by step guide would be much more appreciable.
Thanks.

Comment: 3GB of RAM is too low for Eclipse or Android Studio, IMHO.

Comment: @CommonsWare :( You are right sir. I appreciate this.. is there any other way which I am searching for... like working with eclipse with Gradle Build System..

Comment: You can teach Gradle for Android how to build an Eclipse project. However, I do not know of a recipe to have Eclipse use Gradle for its builds.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Do you think upgrading my system's memory from 3GB to 5GB would produce a significant performance increase with Eclipse/A Studio ?

Comment: Will it help? Certainly. Will it be a "significant" change? That's hard to say. Having high RAM utilization on its own is not really a performance problem. Spilling out of RAM into a swapfile (or the equivalent) is where having limited RAM will hammer your performance. If you can determine how much swap you are using (e.g., **`free`** command in Linux), and if 2GB more RAM might mean you would swap a whole lot less, then it would likely have a significant benefit, at least in terms of how I would define "significant".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [THIS](http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/) Enide Gradle/ Gradle for Eclipse